# The product of any three consecutive natural numbers is divisible by 9.prove or find a counterexample

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, divisibility

can anyone give me feedback on my solution
false counterexample:
n(n+1)(n+2)
let n= 1
1(2)(3)
=6 is not divisible by 9

is this correct?

Comment: Yep, quite right. Could you find a nontrivial counterexample though?

Comment: Yep, that seems like a perfect counter-example to me.
Well done!

Comment: 40*41*42 has only one factor of three, so it's not divisible by 9.

Comment: In fact, a product of three consecutive integers is a multiple of nine iff one of the three factors is a multiple of nine...

Comment: @Ian: I'm not sure what's trivial about this counterexample. (also, one shouldn't discourage the habit of finding trivial examples and counter-examples!)

Comment: I also do not find the counterexample trivial. One could argue that it is the _simplest_ possible counterexample, or the first and most _obvious_ one, but I think the simplest counterexamples are in many ways the best, and there is nothing wrong with it being the "first" possible choice or "obvious".

Answer (score -2):

Indeed, $1\cdot2\cdot3=6$ is not divisible by $9$, so your counterexample works perfectly well.